# Async xhr and callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, jquery-callback

I have a problem with waiting for DOM elems to exist.

First of all, I make an XHR to my backend and get some info from there:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var searchParam, searchStr;
    // some values to vars

    loadTags(15,highlightAndSearchTags(searchParam,searchStr));
});
```

The functions are here:

```
function highlightAndSearchTags(searchParam, searchStr) {
    if (searchParam == 'tags') {
        var selectedTags = searchStr.split(',');
        console.log($("#my_favorite_latin_words").children().length); // sometimes returns 0, sometimes returns number of <span> in the div (see loadTags())
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedTags.length; i++) {
            $("#" + selectedTags[i]).toggleClass("tag-selected");
        }
    }
}

function loadTags(showedTagsLength, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', apiUrl + "tags/", true);
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status != 200) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
            else {
                tagList = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                tagList = tagList.results;

                for (var i = 0; i < showedTagsLength; i++) {
                    $("#my_favorite_latin_words").append("<span id=\'" + tagList[i].tag_pk + "\'>" + tagList[i].name + "</span>");
                }

            }
            setTimeout(callback, 1); //found this trick somewhere on stackoverflow
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

As you can see there is a callback which is executed after 1ms timeout (I found this trick somewhere on stack a while ago), but then another function does not see the appended elements from time to time. 
I have also tried

```
callback.call()
```

with no luck so far.

Can anybody advise how to wait for the elements correctly in this case?

Comment: `loadTags(15,highlightAndSearchTags(searchParam,searchStr));` -> This calls `highlightAndSearchTags(searchParam,searchStr)` immediately and passes the return value (`undefined`) of it to `loadTags` as the `callback`

Comment: the setTimeout "trick" is unnecessary - your problem is as @Andreas pointed out ... do `loadTags(15, function() { highlightAndSearchTags(searchParam,searchStr); });` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 loadTags(15,function(searchParam,searchStr){highlightAndSearchTags(searchParam,searchStr)});
```

As multiple comments already mentioned, you have to wrap it into a function so that it isnt called when you call the loadTags function

Answer (score 1):

```
loadTags(15,highlightAndSearchTags(searchParam,searchStr));
```

This code will execute your function `highlightAndSearchTags` immediately and the result value will be sent instead of your callback, if you want to use it as a callback, you need to only pass the function name like:

```
loadTags(15, highlightAndSearchTags);
```

If you need to pass your `searchParam` and `searchStr` parameters, add them as parameters:

```
loadTags(15, highlightAndSearchTags, searchParam, searchStr);
```

When your tags are loaded, you can directly call your callback with the `searchParam` and `searchStr` parameters you added to your `loadTags` function:

```
function loadTags(showedTagsLength, callback, searchParam, searchStr) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', apiUrl + "tags/", true);
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status != 200) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
            else {
                tagList = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                tagList = tagList.results;

                for (var i = 0; i < showedTagsLength; i++) {
                    $("#my_favorite_latin_words").append("<span id=\'" + tagList[i].tag_pk + "\'>" + tagList[i].name + "</span>");
                }

            }

            callback(searchParam,searchStr);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

Another approach could also be to wrap your callback in an self-executing anonymous function. This will prevent the `highlightAndSearchTags` to be executed immediately so you can call it later when your tags are loaded:

```
loadTags(15, function() { highlightAndSearchTags(searchParam, searchStr); });
```

Comment: Why should I add the parameters of a callback as parameters to the function which should execute the callback? O.o

Comment: I described 2 approaches, adding them as parameters or wrapping your callback in a self-executing anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing any callback function. You are immediately invoking the function and passing the returned value of `highlightAndSearchTags` function which is undefined.

An anonymous function can be created and passed as

```
  loadTags(15,function(){ 
      highlightAndSearchTags(searchParam,searchStr)
  });
```